# Creating overlays in java

Tags: java

Hello I was wondering if anyone can point to a class that can help me with creating an overlay that is like (and I know some people might not know what this is, but those who do stick with this) the curse voice overlay on league of legends, it adds an overlay to your existing game. For those who don't know what that is, and this is the only thing I can think of, is an application that has a completely transparent background with buttons you can click, and this can overlay over games and such.

I just am having issues actually forming what I want to search for on google, wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: try searching css or js lightbox overlay.

Comment: This was java... why did someone change it to javascript...

Comment: I don't think this can be done in Java. You'll need C as you want to inject your program into another.

Comment: What OS are you using? (Odd question for Java) But you will probably need a native lib to help you to achive this

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your overlay window/dialog as DLL (if for Windows) in C or C++
2. Write JNI port for your DLL.
3. Use your overlay directly from Java via JNI port.

This is rather not-easy-to-do-task and if you are biginner, there is a lot of work for yor you to be done.

As an alternative, maybe there are some sort of libs that will make this process easier, but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm really late, but I had the same problem too.
Create a class that extends `Window`, overwrite the `paint` method and use:

```
this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
this.setBounds(this.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
this.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
this.setVisible(true);
```

and then paint in the `paint` method :)